# Fermion masses and $SU(2)$ symmetry

Tags: symmetry, standard-model, dirac-equation, electroweak

Why is the standard mass (Dirac) not compatible with $SU(2)$ symmetry?

I consider the standard mass this
$$ m\bar{e}e = m(\bar{e}_Le_R+ \bar{e}_Re_L)$$

Comment: That's more a coupling between left and right chiral electrons than a mass term. A mass term would look like m $\bar{\psi} \psi$.

Comment: Which $SU(2)$ symmetry?

Comment: Chiral Symmetry

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which $SU(2)$ symmetry you are refering to. There is the $U(1) \times U(1)$ symmetry under
$$
\psi_L \rightarrow e^{i\theta_L} \psi_L, \quad \psi_R \rightarrow e^{i\theta_R} \psi_R
$$
where $\theta_L,\theta_R$ at the $U(1) \times U(1)$ parameters. It is easy to show that $\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m) \psi$ is invariant only if $m = 0$.
Then there is also chiral symmetry, e.g. for QCD with two massless quarks $u$ and $d$, which is $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R \times U(1)_V \times U(1)_A$. For example $SU(2)_L$ acts as to rotate the lefthanded doublets $(u_L,d_L)$ into one another, i.e.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}u_L \\ d_L \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow g_L \begin{pmatrix}u_L \\ d_L \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $g_L \in SU(2)_L$. For more details refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chiral_symmetry. Chiral symmetry is broken by mass terms, which you can readily verify. So I guess that this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the Chiral Symmetry. Thanks. How can I verify that the masses break the chiral symmetry? Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I'm really struggling with this part of the symmetries.

Comment: Show that the Lagrangian is invariant under a general transformation (under the respective group). Can you show it for the $U(1) \times U(1)$ example that I give in my post? If yes, the chiral symmetry case should also be straightforward. Just consider the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = \bar{u}iD_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu} u + \bar{d} i D_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu} d$ and apply for example the $SU(2)_L$ transformation that I mention in my post. Then add mass terms and show that is not invariant.

Comment: Also section 28.2.2 in Schwartz's QFT book might be interesting for you.